# How can I add images to array list, and then add that array list to a view, in Android?

Tags: android

How can I add images to array list, and then add that array list to a view, in Android?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it would be better that you give more details about your problem such as how you get the images or how you are created your View. But I think that the code below will be useful for you.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(9);

for (int i = 0; i < mBitmaps.size; i++)
{
    mBitmaps.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap_src));
}

Collections.shuffle(mBitmaps);

for (int i = 0; i < mBitmaps.size; i++)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = mBitmaps.get(i));

    //Show image in an ImageView
    //...
}
```

I send you an url about create and show BitMaps: 

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CreateBitmap.html